# Positioning of PDF Form XObject without cm?

Tags: forms, pdf

I try to position a PDF Form XObject.

This works:

```
0 0 1 rg 
1 0 0 1 10 10 cm 
/F1 Do
```

This doesn't:

```
0 0 1 rg 
10 10 m 
/F1 Do
```

Why not? Is **cm** the only way to position a Form XObject?

Thanks for all answers and your patience!

Comment: **m** is a command for path building, not a generic command to move the insertion point. **cm** is the generic command to (among other things) move the insertion point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/F1 Do` will always start rendering the source Form XObject at coordinates (0,0), not at the current point, this is why just moving the current point will not work, while doing a translation of the user space does.

An alternative way would be to add a Matrix entry to the XObject dictionary. From the PDF spec:

> When the Do operator is applied to a form XObject, it does the
>   following tasks:
>   1.Saves the current graphics state, as if by invoking the q operator (see Section 4.3.3, “Graphics State Operators”)
>   2.Concatenates the matrix from the form dictionary’s Matrix entry with the current transformation matrix (CTM)
>   3.Clips according to the form dictionary’s BBox entry
>   4.Paints the graphics objects specified in the form’s content stream
>   5.Restores the saved graphics state, as if by invoking the Q operator (see Section 4.3.3, “Graphics State Operators”)